# How to set img size if image not loaded

Tags: html, css

I'm create a custom wysiwyg editor, with custom variables which are filled in from PHP after the content is saved.

For example {image} is a placeholder, which will be filled from PHP after the content saved.

In this case my content template in the HTML code looks like this

```
<img src="{image}" />
```

As this is some kind of drag and drop system, I should be able to drag this item on the wysiwyg canvas, but as that {image} placeholder can't be filled with javascript, the browser won't be able to load any image. As I know in this some old Internet explorer versions give some default "image broken" image into those img's, but modern browsers simply doesn't display it.

So is there any way to make those unloaded images visible(by giving some width and height value and some magic)?

I would like to make this with simple CSS rules without using javascript.

One solution what I have found is to give alt attribute to the images and then that text gives with and height for that element.

Comment: If you give the image a defined width & height, most browsers will still show a broken image icon

Comment: But Firefox doesn't. I need universal solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `onerror`.. so the image will fail to load, but you can then display a 'holding image' to show the end-user that it will be replaced with their real image when published..

```
<img src="{image}" onerror="this.src='http://www.mnit.ac.in/new/PortalProfile/images/faculty/noimage.jpg';" width="100" height="100" />
```

Change the URL to yours.. so something like

```
<img src="{image}" onerror="this.src='/images/temp_image.jpg';" width="100" height="100 />
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7FtfX/

Comment: Thanks, this seems good. Do you know which browsers support onerror event?

Comment: According to quirksmode, when it comes to `img` `src` attribute, pretty much everything: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html

Comment: check out the link @Ennui has provided.. onerror will cover all major browsers.. apart from Opera.. surprise (but who uses that anyway?)

Comment: Looks like even Opera supports the `error` event when it comes to broken image source!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `width` and `height` attributes directly on the `img` element to some modest placeholder size is probably the way to go.  You can also do it CSS, i.e:

```
.wsyiwyg img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #787878;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Another idea which might be better is to use JS to check on all `img` elements and parse the `src` attribute, then replace any with the `{image}` format with a placeholder image `src` (but save the original data and switch it back on save/submit).

Comment: In Firefox 22 the CSS method doesn't work also the my alt method currently seems better for my case than the usage of JS.

Comment: Setting the `width` and `height` attributes directly should be enough in most cases.  The `onerror` attribute solution proposed by Danny is also a pretty simple (and neat) way to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `width`, `height` properties and background. Look at [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RrXXy/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but in Firefox 22 this doesn't work. Sample doesn't work either.

Comment: @RolandSoós, fixed with `display: block;`

Comment: Yes, it seems ok in Firefox with the display block. Also the onerror method what was suggested by @Danny Hearnah is a more elegant way :)